# Issue with InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor not affecting rendering in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, nearest-neighbor

I'm working on a C# application that involves rendering images onto a PictureBox. The images are 640x640 pixels in size, and I'm drawing them onto a destination of the same size. To optimize rendering performance and prioritize speed over image quality, I've tried setting the InterpolationMode to InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor. However, I haven't observed any noticeable change in rendering speed or image quality.

Here's the code snippet where I'm setting the InterpolationMode:

```
using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
{
    // Other settings...
    
    // Set the interpolation mode to NearestNeighbor
    gfx.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    
    // Other drawing operations...
}
```

I've confirmed that the source and destination sizes are both 640x640, so there is no scaling involved. I was expecting this change to improve rendering speed, but I haven't seen a significant effect.

Is there something I might be missing or a common pitfall when using InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor for images that aren't being scaled? Are there other factors that could be affecting the rendering performance?

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting this issue.

Additional Information:

Image size: 640x640
Destination size: 640x640
Using Windows Forms for rendering

Comment: Since they are the same size, why would there be any speed up when no interpolation is done? Also the interpolation wouldn’t really take much time for such images, especially when handled through hardware.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen it's not from hardware but i load it once and save it in memory